# Retornar menor valor de um SUM?

Tags: mysql, select

Eu tenho um `SELECT` com `SUM` e gostaria de entender como faço para me retornar o menor valor da soma de todos valor por fornecedor.

```
SELECT distinct fornecedor, cliente, SUM(valor*qtd) AS TOTAL FROM orcamentos 
WHERE idOrcamento ='$orcamento' group by fornecedor;
```

A Tabela soma todos valores de cada fornecedor.

Eu preciso que o resultado me mostre o menor valor encontrado entre os fornecedores.

Exemplo essa pesquisa acima retornou

|fornecedor | Cliente | TOTAL|

|1________| 1_____       | 10.00|

|2________| 1 _____      | 11.00|

|3________| 1 _____      | 10.50|

Como faço para que o SELECT me retorne somente a linha com menor valor?

Comment: com `min` ..... ou seja, `MIN(valor*qtd)`

Comment: `SELECT cliente, min(valor*qtd) from orcamentos WHERE idOrcamento =$orcamento group by cliente` é o menor por cliente então ???

Comment: correto, com base dos valores de cada fornecedor

Answer (score 3):

### Função SUM

A função `SUM()` retorna a soma total de uma coluna numérica.

### Função MIN

A função `MIN()` retorna o menor valor da coluna selecionada.

### Retornar o menor valor

Como você deseja retornar o menor valor em função sql, você deve usar a função `MIN()` ao invés de usar a função `SUM()` conforme o @VirgilioNovic já respondeu no comentário dele.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
SELECT distinct fornecedor, cliente, 
MIN(valor*qtd) AS TOTAL FROM orcamentos 
WHERE idOrcamento ='$orcamento' group by 
fornecedor, cliente;
```

Comment: Esse SELECT vai retornar o menor valor de cada um dos fornecedores/clientes certo? Acho que o que ele quer é um SELECT que retorne o fornecedor/cliente com menor valor somado

Comment: @JoséHenriqueLuckmann se esta for a dúvida dele então ela ficou mal explicada, seria interessante ele interagir e editar a pergunta para que fique mais clara.

Comment: @Wendell obrigado, refiz a pergunta para deixar mais claro, tenteni MIN(SUM()) mas me retornou erro.